# need to create sperated data in combination chart (limitless)

Tags: php

### // Add series

```
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Internet Explorer',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'Total',
                    data: [320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320] // set quantity of top 10 product of seven days
                },
                {
                    name: 'Opera',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'Total',
                    data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Safari',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'Total',
                    data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Firefox',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'Total',
                    data: [150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    type: 'bar',
                    stack: 'Total',
                    data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320]
                }
            ]
        };
```

in data i have to set quantity dynamically to get top 10 product of seven days

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: SELECT opd.productid,pm.productname,
IFNULL(SUM(opd.quantity), 0) AS quantity,
date(orderdate) as orderdate  from ordermaster as om
inner join orderproductdetails as opd
on om.orderid=opd.orderid and om.locationid=opd.locationid
and opd.isdeleted=0                 
inner join productmaster as pm
on opd.productid=pm.productid and pm.isdeleted=0
AND DATE(om.orderdate)='2019-12-23'
group by productid
order by quantity desc limit 0,10 // this is my query and i have to set query resuslt in above fomat

Comment: I mean to say add this code in your question and format it properly. visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask